# Android Spinner Error, When Viewing Mysql Table using PHP

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am getting Invalid IP Address when i am running this application on emulator as well as on real android device. I had copied this content from net.

Code of MainActivity.java is below:

```
package com.himanshu.spinnerdynamic;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    InputStream is=null;
    String result=null;
    String line=null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://himanshuchawla.me/evikasnagar/spinner.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("Pass 1", "connection success ");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }     

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("Pass 2", "connection success ");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
        }     

        try
        {
            JSONArray JA=new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json= null;
            final String[] str1 = new String[JA.length()];        
            final String[] str2 = new String[JA.length()];

            for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
            {
                json=JA.getJSONObject(i);
                str1[i] = json.getString("id");
                str2[i]=json.getString("category_name");
            }

            final Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int i=0;i<str2.length;i++)
            {
                list.add(str2[i]);
            }

            Collections.sort(list);

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            sp.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

            sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
            {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long id) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String item=sp.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Log.e("Item",item);
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

MySql Database is like this

```
    id    |    category_name
----------------------------------
    1     |    Software Companies
    2     |    Garment Shops
----------------------------------
```

Android Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.himanshu.spinnerdynamic"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.himanshu.spinnerdynamic.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

spinner.php PHP Code Is:

```
<?php


$host = "xxxx";
$uname = "xxxx";
$pwd = "xxxx";
$db = "xxxx";

    $con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

    $r=mysql_query("select * from shop_category",$con);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
    {
        $cls[]=$row;
    }

    print(json_encode($cls));
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

When I am running spinner.php on browser it is showing like this:

```
[{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"Software Companies","category_name":"Software Companies"},{"0":"2","id":"2","1":"Garment Shops","category_name":"Garment Shops"}]
```

I am not able to run this app., getting INVALID IP ADDRESS after running this app. please help. your help will be appreciated.

Comment: This code would generate [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). Are you sure that isn't your problem? In your `catch`, do `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Ya, i am getting NetworkOnMainThreadException error.

Answer (score 0):

**Network operations are forbidden inside the main thread.**

To do so, create an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and
move your `network` code to `doInBackground` method. After you processed your info, update your UI inside the method `onPostExecute`